# bash remove duplicate files based on sequence number at the end

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hy,

I'm trying to delete some duplicate files in a folder (aprox. 50000 files) that have the same name but the only thing that differs is a sequence number at the end :

```
aaaaaaaaaa.ext.84837384
aaaaaaaaaa.ext.44549388
aaaaaaaaaa.ext.22134455
bbbbbbbbbb.ext.11244355
bbbbbbbbbb.ext.88392456
```

I want to delete the duplicate files based on minimum of sequence number (.22134455 to be hold for aaaaaaaaaa.ext and .11244355 to be hold for bbbbbbbbbbb)

I mentioned that i have a lot of files in the folder ~ 50.000 files and sorting and filtering based on size and md5 would take like forever.

I tried `find -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d | xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate` but is taking forever.

Thank you very much

Comment: why are you filtering files base on size?

Comment: So you're running `find` once for each file and wondering why it's taking a long time?  Stop running `find` inside `xargs`!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
find . -name '*.ext.*' -print0 | sort -z | awk -v RS='\0' -F. '{fn=$0; num=$NF; $NF=""; if(a[$0]){printf "%s\0", fn};a[$0]++;}' | xargs -n 100 -0 rm -f
```

Explanation:

1. `find . -name '*.ext.*' -print0`: Print filenames delimited by a null character.
2. `sort -z`: Sort zero delimited entries.
3. `awk`: separate records by null character & fields by a `.`. strip off the last field - number & remember the remaining filename. Except for the first entry, print other file names, separated by null character.
4. `xargs -0`: receive null char separated filenames on stdin & rm -f them.

Assumption: All the files are in the current directory.

Add `-maxdepth 1` option to find command, if there are sub-directories & you want to skip iterating through them.

Comment: `*.ext.*` is likely to fail.  Use `find ... -name='*.ext.*'` (or even just `ls` and filter inside `awk`)

Comment: If they are in sub-directories, then we need find. If they are in current directory, `printf '%s\0' *.ext.*` should work, right? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If there are many files in the directory, the glob expansion can fail.  (Although apparently this failure is an old bug which doesn't show up in modern shells.)

Comment: hy, this is not doing anything. nothing is removed :(

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Oh, I missed that part - "i have a lot of files in the folder ~ 50.000 files". Thansk for your comment.

Comment: still nothing deleted . awk prints nothing

Comment: Can you check the output of individual stage? First check `ls` & then output of `find`, `find | sort`, `find|sort|awk` etc... Because this command pipeline works on my system.

Comment: when i arrive to awk ... the output is nothing . `find . -name '*.cdr.*' -print0 | sort -z` prints : `./aaaa.cdr.1123433./aaaa.cdr.2344312./aaaa.cdr.3224112./aaaa.cdr.9999212./bbbb.cdr.2333211./bbbb.cdr.3331123./bbbb.cdr.5522321./cccc.cdr.1234222`

Comment: What is your `awk --version`?

Comment: `awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74233/discussion-between-anishsane-and-123onetwothree).

Answer (score 1):

This script will remove all duplicated files in the directory that's in.

List and sort files by filename, sequence number will be used to sort duplicates, then remove the file if it was already 'visited', else just saved the filename minus sequence in a temporary variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp_filename=

for full_filename in `ls | sort`; do
    filename=$(basename "$full_filename")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"

    if [[ "$tmp_filename" == "$filename" ]]; then
        rm "$full_filename"
    else
        tmp_filename="$filename"
    fi
done
```

Comment: you script actually work . thank you very much . the other answer works too but i dont have the GNU awk tool installed so your answer fits my problem. thank you very much